# Shuffling up Variables in Sql Server for Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Ok . The Requirement is say i have a TVF
              **fn ( a ,b ,c d)**
Now the data in these variables must be shuffled if there are any gaps between them. 
For Example

Input
1. a = 1,b= NULL,c=3,d=4
2. a=NULL ,B=NULL,c=3,d=NULL

Output of TVF

1.a=1,b=3,c=4,NULL

2.a=3,b=NULL,c=NULL,d=NULL

So the output must have all the Non NULL Values then the NULL's.
What I mean to say is there must not me any gap in output .
Can u guys please suggest a way of doing this? . I'm thinking of using cursors?
is it efficient ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Null` check and `PIVOT` is done

```
DECLARE @a int = 1, @b int, @c int = 3, @d int = 4

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) + 96) Seq, 
        Value 
    FROM (VALUES(@a), (@b), (@c), (@d)) data(Value)
    WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
) data
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value) FOR Seq IN ([a], [b], [c], [d])
) p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a combination of conditional aggregation.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eabf2/1/0)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Fn(
    @a  INT = NULL,
    @b  INT = NULL,
    @c  INT = NULL,
    @d  INT = NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN

WITH CteRN(RN, N) AS(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN N IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                    N
                ),
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT @a UNION ALL
        SELECT @b UNION ALL
        SELECT @c UNION ALL
        SELECT @d
    )t(N)
)
SELECT
    a = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN N END),
    b = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN N END),
    c = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN N END),
    d = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN N END)
FROM CteRN
```